# Angular 4 component not seen in child modules

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am trying to get the following component to be seen in all children modules of the AppModule. Why can't I get the loader01 component without importing it in the child module when it is imported in the AppModule module. This is my component.

```
//app\utilities\loader01\loader01.component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'Loader01',
  templateUrl: './loader01.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader01.component.css']
})
export class Loader01Component implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This component is part of a shared module which I have imported into the Root AppModule;

```
//app\utilities\utilities.module.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  declarations: [Loader01Component],
  exports: [
    Loader01Component
  ]
})
export class UtilitiesModule { }
```

My AppModule looks like this;

```
//app\app.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AppConfigModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ToasterModule,
    HttpInterceptorModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot(),
    UtilitiesModule
  ],
  exports: [ToasterModule],
  providers: [
    Title,
    AuthGuard,
    AuthenticationService,
    UserService,
    SweetAlertService,
    InterfaceService,
    PermissionService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Clearly the UtilitiesModule is included in the AppModule so I would expect it to be available in all children modules. But this is not the case.

I have a child module UsersModule which is a child of the LayoutModule which is a child of the AppModule and a PermissionModule which is a child of the UsersModule. And I am accessing the UsersModule and PermissionModule using the router under the following urls.

```
#/users
#/users/permissions
```

The PermissionModule where I want to see the Loader01Component looks like this;

```
//app\utilities\loader01\loader01.component.ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PermissionsRoutingModule,
    NgbModalModule,
    NgbPaginationModule
  ],
  declarations: [PermissionsComponent, EditComponent, CreateComponent]
})
export class PermissionsModule { }
```

The Loader01Component is not seen in this module. This component is part of the PermissionModule. The only way to see it in this module is to import the UtilitiesModule in the PermissionModule. But I don't think this is right since UtilitiesModule is already included in the AppModule which is a parent of the UsersModule which is a parent of the PermissionModule. I think Angular routing has something to do with it which I have not learnt yet.

I am using routes to access all my children modules. Here is

```
//app\app-routing.module.ts
import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
    //{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
            { enableTracing: true, useHash: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

My LayoutModule also does the same thing to include it's children modules. This is my LayoutModule routing;

```
//app\layout\layout-routing.module.ts
const routes: Routes = [{ path: '', component: LayoutComponent, children: [
  //{ path: '', redirectTo: 'users', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '', loadChildren: '../dashboard/dashboard.module#DashboardModule' },
  { path: 'users', loadChildren: '../users/users.module#UsersModule' }
]}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class LayoutRoutingModule { }
```

And this is the routing for my parent AppModule where the UtilitiesModule is included;

```
//app\app-routing.module.ts

import { AuthGuard } from './_guards/auth.guard';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]},
    { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
    //{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot(
            appRoutes,
            { enableTracing: true, useHash: true } // <-- debugging purposes only
        )
    ],
    exports: [
        RouterModule
    ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: "LayoutModule which is a child of the AppModule" I don't see `LayoutModule` imported in your `AppModule`

Comment: I have included the LayoutModule by using routes;
{path: '', loadChildren: './layout/layout.module#LayoutModule', canActivate: [AuthGuard]}

Comment: I'm not sure of the scope of LayoutModule in this case. If it's loaded isolated from container module (AppRoutingModule)

Comment: I think you need to import the SharedModule in your lazy loaded module as well. Example: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule#no-shared-module-providers

Comment: LayoutModule is also the Root of all modules. It also loads all other components that must be seen at all time when the app is loaded. It also has the <router-outlet></router-outlet> so all the body/content for my routes is loaded here.

Comment: Yes, it works when I included the SharedModule in the lazy loaded module. This is the only way to archive this? I mean I have to do this for all my lazy loaded modules throughout the app? It seems like a lot of work to do it for every module. Can't I just have it everywhere? I would think it is available in the AppModule it will be automatically loaded in the lazy loaded module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Providers` work the way you want, however this is not the case with `Component`s.

Since you have an `UtilitiesModule` that declares your `Loader01Component` and export it, you have to import `UtilitiesModule` in every module in which you want to use `Loader01Component`

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [UtilitiesModule]
})
export class UserModule
```

**One important note:** Do not provide any service from your `UtilitiesModule` because of Angular dependency injection. Lazy loaded modules get their own instances of services.
You can read more at here: https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#why-is-it-bad-if-sharedmodule-provides-a-service-to-a-lazy-loaded-module

Comment: That is exactly what OP does in `UtilitiesModule` and Components do not go in the `imports` array, they should be in the `declarations`

Comment: Sorry yeah, I fixed it. Thanks

Comment: How can I use a provider in this case to make sure that the Loader01Component html is always in any module without having to import it again and again. Sort of like a global component or directive that I can use everywhere.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not possible.